# Magic methods (__get, __set) not working in extended class?

Tags: php

```
<?php 

abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public function __get($theName)
    {
        return (isset($this->$theName)) ? $this->$theName : NULL;
    }

    public function __set($theName, $theValue)
    {
        if (false === property_exists(get_class(), $theName)) {
            throw new Exception(get_class()." does not have '".$theName."' property.");
        } else {
            $this->$theName = $theValue;
        }
    }
}

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass
{
        private $x;
        private $y;

        public function __construct($theX, $theY)
        {
            $this->x = $theX;
            $this->y = $theY;
        }
}

$concreteClass = new ConcreteClass(10, 20);

var_dump( $concreteClass->x );
```

Is there some way to amke this work or will I have to add those magic methods to the extended class?

Comment: what exactly goes wrong? is x empty? you may need to set $x and $y in the base class for this to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would work:

```
public function __get($theName)
{
    if(property_exists($this, $theName)) {
        $reflection = new ReflectionProperty($this, $theName);
        $reflection->setAccessible($theName);
        return $reflection->getValue($this);
    }
}
```

IMO, you shouldn't use `__get` and `__set` as a replacement for getters and setters. Since they are triggered when trying to access a non-accessible property, they are much more related to error-handling. And they are also much slower than a regular getter or setter.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to make my life easier nad have one abstract class for all my classes with defined getters and setters. I have too many get and set methods already.

Comment: This performance difference is based on the fact that by using magic methods at runtime there is a check if these methods are present and if so they are called for the inaccessible properties. By using explicit getter and setter methods these checks are omit resulting in a slightly better performance.

As mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634748/php-zend-say-avoid-magic-methods?rq=1 there is a difference of 0,1s for a million magic methods calls which is not a common use case. Imho it is micro-optimizing bullshit. If you need to do so, then you code has bigger problems.

Comment: In this case, I recommend reading the books by Robert C. Martin aka Uncle Bob.
If you need this kind of micro-optimization, then in most cases some of these problems are in the code base:
Wrong architecture / violation of one or more principles of S.O.L.I.D, old technology ...
Most of the time this happens when you want to make every customer happy and so a special customization is implemented here and there and the code grows into an unmaintainable monstrosity until it ends up either refactoring/rewriting or the software is maybe replacing by a new one and the cycle starts again.

Comment: @AlexanderBehling it's funny that you recommend Uncle Bob's books and SOLID because shoehorning getters and setters through a magic method is very much violating SOLID and Clean Code principles. It's not about the performance (that is a side note in my answer). It's about assigning responsibility in the right places instead of having one method catching all the access.

Comment: @Gordon
I'm sorry, but I don't understand how using magic methods violates SOLID or Clean code.
Could you please explain it to me and all other readers so that we all can benefit from your knowledge?

Comment: @AlexanderBehling Clean Code G30: Functions should do one thing. If all your access logic is in magic methods, you are violating that heuristic. If you want to access or mutate a value, write a dedicated method. That will be much cleaner than switch/casing for the property name and adding logic. Also from a self documenting code perspective. I want to look at the interface of a class and know what it does. With magic methods it won't tell me (unless you put an extensive block of annotations which are always at risk of getting outdated). Method signatures never outdate.

Comment: Also G17 Misplaced responsibility. As I said in my answer already, magic methods trigger when trying to access a non-accessible property. That's an error case. It shouldnt result in a mutation of the property or retrieval. That's what accessors are for.

Comment: Now I see your point.
Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that the $x and $y members set in the `ConcreteClass` are private. Since the `__get()` method is defined in the parent class, it does not have the access to the child class's private members (since private members are accessible only by the class itself, not by any child or parent class). For them to be visible to the parent class, they have to be either `protected` or `public`. For your case, you'd have to use protected to maintain the magical function outside the class.

This, however, is a very odd practice at best. If the variables can be accessed via magic methods, there is no much point in making them private in the first place.

Comment: This was the problem for me. Makes a lot of sense setting to protected. This is not an odd practice however ... if you write your magic functions properly, then it either acts as a simple accessor function (getting/setting the value) ... but it first checks if other "get_PROPERTY" or "set_PROPERTY" functions have been specified. If they have, those are returned. I found this useful because the bulk of my properties can just be get/set normally, but some have an action applied (i.e. a trim() or something) or validation logic.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `x` and `y` belong to `ConcreteClass`, while parent`s functions only work for parent`s properties. For instance if you had:

```
abstract class AbstractClass
{
    private $x;
//...
}
class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass
{
        private $y;

        public function __construct($theX, $theY)
    //...
```

then it would've worked. Parent can't access child's private properties, you must reconsider your object structure if you ran into this.

**Update**

As Rinuwise said you can make `x` and `y` visible by declaring them protected or public, but it's still wrong logic.

Also as an alternative you can copy-paste the `__get` method from AbstractClass to ConcreteClass, providing that way the parent access to private properties of its descedant; but again "you *can* do that" doesn't mean "you *must* do that":).