# How to prevent a false-warning in PhpStorm when the return-type is deduced incorrectly?

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

Consider the following code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
/**
 * Class MyModel
 * @package App\Models
 * @mixin Builder
 */
class MyModel extends Model
{
    public static function getGreens(): Builder
    {
        return (new self())->where('color', '=', 'green');
    }
}
```

On the `return` statement, the PhpStorm (2020.3) complains that:

> Return value is expected to be `'\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder'`, `'MyModel'` returned

And suggest to:

> Change return type from `'\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder'` to `'MyModel'`

which is weirdly incorrect (the [`where`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_where) method does return an instance of `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`, while the IDE deduces the return type as being of `MyModel` type). By removing the return type, the IDE issues another warning:

> Missing function's return type declaration

The code works without any problems, but the IDE shouldn't report any *false* warnings! How should I avoid these warnings in PhpStorm?

[image: PhpStorm (2020.3) complains that: "Return value is expected to be '\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder', 'MyModel' returned"]

Comment: How it seems to me, [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes) should be used.

Comment: As I understand (from what I remember how Laravel works) it's because of `@mixin` line. `@mixin` works similar to how **trait** works. So if you have a method in a trait that returns `$this` / `self` and then use that trait in a class, then return of that method  (`$this/self`) points to the class where it is used. Now, AFAIR `Builder::where()` also returns `$this / self` .. but it's not actually a trait .. but Laravel magically makes the `where()` method available in this class...

Comment: And here comes the problem: that `$this / self` actually points to the `Builder` class but  when used **as a trait** (because of `@mixin`) it gets resolved to the current `MyModel` class by the IDE.

Comment: You either use `@mixin` and live with ignoring the issue (you can use error suppression via `Alt+Enter` quick fix menu -- it will add a comment for IDE to tell to ignore that specific issue here) .. or remove `@mixin` and declare those methods differently. AFAIK Laravel helper package should add all such Builder methods to the Model class via `'@method` PHPDoc lines (look into that for details). Another suggestion -- try **Laravel Idea** plugin -- it's a PAID plugin but it makes working with Laravel code much easier and AFAIK it should cover such basic stuff.

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for your elaborate comments, they even fit into a complete answer as well! So, do you think the implementation of the `@mixin` in the PhpStorm should be aware of such a scenario and expose a fine-grained behavior on the issue; or it's the source-codes that need to be addressed to avoid the problem?

Comment: `@mixin` tag was created to mimic PHP's trait (as it was **long before** traits were introduced, e.g. Yii and few other frameworks used them, called "behaviours" or something like that). Here comes Laravel that uses it all differently (mainly because of typehints presence) ... why should it be changed to satisfy one framework (and most likely break in another)? Original "implement @mixin" request ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1730

Comment: Related (as for me) tickets -- not your situation, but related (and I guess some comments will be similar to your case): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34809, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-49567

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a result of not following the "best practices". The class-hierarchy of `MyModel` does not provide a method of `where`; in other words, such a method does not exist in the class-hierarchy. But! The parent class of [`Model`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php) does provide a [magic method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) of [`__call()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1875) which gets triggered when an *inaccessible method* in the object context is invoked (in your case, the method of `where`). It essentially [forwards the "call"](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1885) to a new instance of `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`, that has the implementation of the requested method (it's acquired from invoking the method of [`newQuery()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1170)). This mechanism is not only IDE-unfriendly, but also [slower](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3634783/3709765).

Thus; drop the `@mixin` tag, and instead of utilizing the "magic methods", use "native access":

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class MyModel extends Model
{
    public static function getGreens(): Builder
    {
        return (new self())->newQuery()->where('color', '=', 'green');
        //                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As I understand (based on how Laravel works) it's because of `@mixin` line.

`@mixin` tag works similar to how PHP's native **trait** works. So if you have a method in a trait that returns `$this` / `self` and then use that trait in a class, then return of that method (`$this/self`) points to the class where it is used.

Now, [`Builder::where()`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_where) method also returns `$this` or `self` ... but it's not actually a trait but Laravel magically makes that `where()` method available in this class.

And here comes the problem: that `@return $this` actually points to the `Builder` class but when used "as a trait" (because of `@mixin`) it gets resolved to the current `MyModel` class by the IDE.

---

You either use `@mixin` and live with ignoring the issue (you can use error suppression via <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> quick fix menu -- it will add a comment for IDE to tell to ignore that specific issue here) .. or remove `@mixin` and declare those methods differently.

AFAIK [Laravel helper package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) should add all such Builder methods to the `Model` class via `@method` PHPDoc lines (look into that for details, go through past issues there to see how and why it does that etc, e.g. [#541](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/issues/541)).

Another suggestion: try [Laravel Idea plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13441-laravel-idea) -- it's a PAID plugin but it makes working with Laravel code much easier and AFAIK it should cover such basic stuff.

---

For reference:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1730 -- original request for documenting/supporting mixins
- Outstanding `@mixin` tickets that can be related here (at least partially):

  - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34809
  - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-49567
  - or try your own search, e.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI?q=mixin%20laravel