# PhpStorm: Is there a way to enforce a type on the return statement using an inline PHPDoc annotation?

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, phpdoc, type-annotation

Consider the following code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Car extends Model
{
    public static function getTheFirstCar(string $color): ?self
    {
        /** @var ?self */ // <-- Doesn't apply! Is there any alternative?
        return (new self())->newQuery()->firstWhere('color', '=', $color);
    }
}
```

The code is working correctly; nevertheless PhpStorm complains:

> Return value is expected to be '`Car|null`',
> '`\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`' returned
>
> [image: PhpStorm PHPDoc Type Annotation on return statement]

Assigning the result of the expression into an annotated variable resolves the warning, but yet introduces a *"redundant"* variable!

```
/** @var ?self $redundant */
$redundant = (new self())->newQuery()->firstWhere('color', '=', $color);
return $redundant;
```

So, is there a way in PhpStorm to enforce an inline type-annotation for the value of the `return` statement expression explicitly as `Car|null`, without introducing a redundant variable or specifying all of the expected return types?

Comment: You can add `@return ?static|Model` above the method. The problem itself looks like [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-58031)

Comment: @Dmitrii I don't want to introduce ambiguity by adding the irrelevant-to-the-context type of `Model` (the method only returns `Car` or `null`)

Comment: What phpstorm version are you using?

Comment: I used the 2020.3.2 and it's work fine. Maybe you should be to update the phpstorm.

Comment: @Dmitry I also use PhpStorm v2020.3.2 (Build #PS-203.7148.74); Please elaborate on *"what" works fine* for you? (Is it the `/** @var ?self */` before the return statement (which is in line of what I need); or, the addition of  the irrelevant-to-the-context type of `Model` -- which I explained it off!)

Comment: @goodUser  In my case the PhpStorm don't complains

Comment: Also you can to try reload the phpstom with cache. `file > invalidate Caches/Restart...`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can suppress this warning by adding the `@noinspection PhpIncompatibleReturnTypeInspection` annotation before your statement.
**I personally would not do this**, but it's the only answer to you your question about how to "enforce" the return type and suppress warning afaik.

```
    /** @noinspection PhpIncompatibleReturnTypeInspection */
    return (new self())->newQuery()->where('color', '=', $color)->first();
```

**If you decide to respect the warning**, then this is probably the reason and solution for it:
`newQuery()` will create a new query on the models table (most likely: `cars`) without setting the appropriate model (`Car`).
Internally you're now running a bare query on `cars`. Therefore you will receive the appropriate record but is not gonna be an instance of `Car`, but an instance of `Model` instead. Therefore PhpStorm is expecting multiple additional return types here and printing this warning on your statement since it differs from the methods return type `?self`.

The quick solution is to change `newQuery()` into `newModelQuery()`. This will create a new query and set the Model `Car` on the created query and return the appropriate instance or null

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Car extends Model
{
    public static function getTheFirstCar(string $color): ?self
    {
        return (new self())->newModelQuery()->firstWhere('color', '=', $color);
        // I'd use this statement though:
        // return self::where('color', '=', $color)->first();
    }
}
```

Comment: A nice and _"native"_ solution boosted together with elaborative descriptions; I do really appreciate it; thank you. I was also wondering, why you'd rather to use the "magic"-method approach instead, as [it causes just another warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65551067/14063881)?

Comment: I know that laravel facades is an contested approach. I personally like that approach and got already used to it. In case I really need some autocompletion or would like to omit the warning, then I simply create an \@method or \@property annotation. Another good option is to use the ide-plugin, but in my recent projects I dont even considered to add it to my dependencies tbh.

Comment: It is worth noting `newModelQuery` does not register global scopes and is not entirely analagous to `newQuery` with a model set. Docs: "Get a new query builder that doesn't have any global scopes or eager loading."

Answer (score 2):

[As of PhpStorm 2022.2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2022/06/phpstorm-2022-2-eap-5/#anonymous_var_in_return_statements_wi) anonymous `@var` annotations are supported, so your code already should work as is:

```
/** @var self */
return (new self())->newQuery()->firstWhere('color', '=', $color);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add doc block to your class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
/**
 * Class Car
 * @package App\Models
 *
 * @method self|Builder newQuery()
 * @method ?self firstWhere($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and')
 */
class Car extends Model
{
    public static function getTheFirstCar(string $color): ?self
    {
        return (new self())->newQuery()->firstWhere('color', '=', $color);
    }
}
```

Comment: But if you add `@method self|Builder newQuery()` in class-level doc-block, the inline doc-block is unnecessary. But the OP want to use this way.