# zendframework action helper to display form

Tags: zend-framework

I want to have a login form when i click www.example.com/login with the help of action helper .
My controllers/helpers directory contain the file name 
the class Login.php is

In my views/login/index.phtml i m calling it like this

```
<?= $this->loginForm; ?>


Login.php
<? 
class Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Login extends
Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    function Login($a)
    {
        //Consists of form elements

    }
}


?>
```

I get the following error ---------

```
"Helper "login" does not support overloading via direct()"
```

How to display the  form and what is the error about ?

Comment: How are you calling the helper?

Comment: In my views/login/index.phtml i m calling it like this  <?=  $this->loginForm; ?>

Comment: I mean how are you calling the Login action helper? You can't call action helpers from your view.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058751/how-does-the-method-syntax-public-function-direct-work-in-php. Create an empty direct method.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it right this way .

http://geekabyte.blogspot.nl/2012/08/understanding-zend-frameworks-plugin.html
in the Bootstrap.php

```
public function _initLoader()
{

    //For configuring  Zend Application to be aware of the Controller Action Helper
 Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(APPLICATION_PATH .'/controllers/helpers'); 

}
```

The LoginController.php

```
class LoginController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_helper->login->scream();
    }
}
```

In the controller/helpers/Login.php

```
class Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Login extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    Public function scream()
    {
        echo  "Here please help!!!";
    }

}
```